# How to test windows iso usb boot

Tags: windows, flash, bootable-media

I just created a windows 7 iso to usb drive boot. How can I test to make sure it works. I used the windows tool I found online. Thanks!

Comment: Assuming you created it correctly, insert in a computer, start it up to boot from the USB key and then cancel the install ("Are you sure you wish to install Windows")

Comment: I put in the drive but it launches windows. It does not read my flash device. I was reading online and it said to change boot order. Do I need to do that or will just plugging I  usb device work. Also is that the best way to test or is there another method?

Comment: That says that the drive did not boot / is not bootable.  Try remaking the USB or try making the USB key with Rufus:  https://www.techspot.com/downloads/6062-rufus.html

Comment: Do I have to change the boot order. My bios says notebook drive. So I have to change the boot order to see if the flash drive works? Also tried rufus could not figure the options I need to select.

Comment: You can change the boot order or, there may be a Fn-Key function to boot from a different device (the latter depends on the laptop make/model)

Comment: I can acess bios by pressing esc key. Then I think i can change boot order. How do I find the fn key for laptop maker? Or just do esc then bios then boot order?

Comment: (a) you can look in the laptop documentation (b) it may be easiest, since you can get into BIOS, to put USB drive first.

Comment: Make and model of PC?

Answer (score 0):

If your tool was legit it probably already checked the files. If you didn't get any errors saying it failed to create the boot drive it should be fine.

Comment: I used the tool in windows and I read the flash drive it does have files..so probably working

Answer (score 0):

Press ESC to enter BIOS > select the USB you want to boot from by pressing Enter (other keys used to navigate are generally mentioned at the bottom) > Boot from the USB ;

Refer [this](https://www.reneelab.com/product-land-184.html)for help ;

If can't boot/not sure USB bootable or not - Try  making bootable USB using [Rufus](https://rufus.ie)